# Show a specific value using DAX in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to show a specific value in a card report, this is a cashflow example:

[image: Cash workflow]

The columns are: `Data = Date`, `Tipo = Type` (Cash in (`Entrada`) or (Cash out (`Saída`)), `Valor = Valu`e, `Saldo final de caixa = Final cash balance`.

None of this columns are calculated columns.

So I just want to click on the Date slicer, select the day, and return the value of the `Saldo final de caixa = Final cash balance`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start out by creating a simple "Sum" measure like this:

```
Final Cash Balance Sum := sum(table[Saldo final de caixa])
```

Then you can just reference this measure in a card and it will react to the date in the slicer you've selected.

Since you can have multiple transactions a day, you will need to have either a timestamp or a rank for each transaction. Once this field is included in your model you could do something like this:

```
Final Cach Balance Sum := CALCULATE(Table[Saldo Final De Caixa]; FILTER(Table; Table[rank] = max(Table[rank])));
```

Comment: Thanks, but if we have two or more registers in same date? For example if I choice 21/01/2017 the card shows me R$4503,30. The correct is show me R$2993,82.

Comment: Then I would recommend you using the CALCULATE function:

Comment: How are these "Valor" values being ranked? It seems like for a given day you could have N transactions and have no idea what order they occurred in. If you could set up a rank on them based on the time of the transaction then you could use the CALCULATE function. E.g. Final Cash Balance Sum := calculate(table[Saldo Final de Caixa]; filter( table; table[rank] = max(table[rank])));

Comment: I obtain these data from an Excel sheet, the registers are inserted from top to bottom, and yes, we have N transactions by day, I was wondering we create an index column could help to rank the last date inserted?

Comment: Is not acepting the first argument in calculate: calculate('Fluxo de caixa'[Saldo final de caixa]; filter('Fluxo de caixa';'Fluxo de caixa'[Índice] = max('Fluxo de caixa'[Índice])))     índice mean index

Comment: Try this: calculate(sum('Fluxo de caixa'[Saldo final de caixa]); filter('Fluxo de caixa';'Fluxo de caixa'[Índice] = max('Fluxo de caixa'[Índice]))) you made need a function to calculate on, and since you are referencing the max index it should produce what you need.

Comment: I just need to click on the up arrow on your answer isn't?